# IOS: German characters appear as japanese

Tags: iphone, ios, encoding, utf-8

I've got IOS app that scans QR codes using ZBarSDK. The problem is when i try to scan code with german characters, they appear as japanese in the app.

For example: code containing - 
Einsteinstraße 54
81675 München/Germany will have japanese characters instead of ß and ü.

Any ideas how this could possibly be fixed?

P.S. Using android Barcode Scanner it appears properely.

My code:

```
-(IBAction)StartScan:(id) sender
{
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    reader.readerView.torchMode = 0;
    reader.tracksSymbols = YES;
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_I25 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
    [self presentModalViewController: reader
                            animated: YES];
    scanner = nil;
}
```

and

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    for(symbol in results) {
        self.hiddenData=[NSString stringWithString:symbol.data];
        NSLog(@"SymbolData: %@", [symbol data]);
    }
    resultTextView.text=symbol.data;
    NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [storeData setObject:self.hiddenData forKey:@"CONSUMERID"];
    NSLog(@"SYMBOL : %@",self.hiddenData);
    //rest of code...
}
```

[symbol data] contains japanese characters instead of german already.

Comment: can you post your code? are you using UTF8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, im using UTF8 encoding in X-code

Comment: can you please try to display your [symbol data] in an textField or textView. In console you get sometimes wrong characters. have you also checked your code with another scanner/reader?

Comment: I displayed [symbol data] in UITextView and it displayed japanese characters instead of german ones. I checked QR code with another scanner (android Barcode Scanner) and it appeared as it should (with german characters). One of my ideas is that SDK that I'm using is broken somehow or I did something wrong with it.

Comment: no, the sdk should be ok. maybe the issue is in your QR code. try to generate one more code with correct ü in HTML. in case of ü use `&uuml;`. where is the place you set your encoding? can you paste that code, too?

Comment: The QR code that I'm using is: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=|Name:%20Dummy%20name%20%C3%9F%C3%9F%20|Address:%20Dummy%20address%20%C3%9F%C3%9F%20|Amount:%2012.00%20EUR  

I set encoding of file to UTF-8, don't have it in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem, i solved it with:

```
NSString* barcode = symbol.data; 

if ([barcode canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSShiftJISStringEncoding]) { 
    barcode = [NSString stringWithCString:[barcode cStringUsingEncoding: NSShiftJISStringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
}
```

Maby it works for you.